# Print a large list of lists

Tags: r

I have a dataset that's ~4GB+.

The structure is

```
UniqueID    Tags
1           1, 37, 284
2           1, 284
3           234, 456, 789
...
```

I want to write this to a file, however it's giving me an issue since

```
typeof(structure) = list
```

and

```
typeof(structure$Tags) = list
```

I'm hoping to write it to a table exactly as pictured, with 1 column being the UniqueID, and the next column being that second list printed out.

When I attempt to write it currently using

```
write.table(structure, output_file, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE,quote=FALSE)
```

I get

```
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Which I am pretty sure is due to my table having a list within it.

Edit : I should add, I tried doing 
    structure$tags = paste(structure$tags, collapse="")

but then my result is saved with the format

```
"c(Tag1, Tag2, ..., TagN)"
"c(Tag1, Tag284, ... )"
```

Comment: Did you try writing it as `rds` file via `writeRDS`? - have a look here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/readRDS.html

Comment: Do you want to be able to read the data into another program or just save it so that it can easily be loaded back into R?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new data frame and write it.

```
tagLists <- sapply(structure$tags, paste, collapse = ",")
df <- data.frame(unique_ids = structure$unique_ids, tags = tagLists)
```